# Java 8 Optional <List> returning True Why?

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, java-8, option-type

I have a REST Controller

```
@GetMapping("/getByClientId/{clientId}")
 public ResponseEntity<Optional<List<EquityFeeds>>> getByClientId(@PathVariable("clientId") final String clientId) {

 Optional<List<EquityFeeds>> cId = Optional.ofNullable(equityFeedsService.findByClientId(clientId));

  System.out.println("Client Id: "+cId);

        if(cId.isPresent()) {
           return ResponseEntity.ok(cId);
        } else {
           cId.orElseThrow(() -> new ClientIdNotFoundException(clientId));
        }
        return ResponseEntity.ok(cId);
     }
```

Service Class Code:

```
public List<EquityFeeds> findByClientId(String clientId) {

        List<EquityFeeds> cId = equityFeedsRedisRepositoryImpl.findByClientId(clientId);
        System.out.println("In EquityFeedService "+cId);
        return cId;
    }
```

Impl. Code (REDIS):

```
public List<EquityFeeds> findByClientId(String clientId) {
      return (List<EquityFeeds>) listOperations.range(clientId, 0, -1);
}
```

Issue: 
1) When the getClientId is called using a REST Controller and the clientId is not present in the REDIS Cache then:

```
Service class Code returns: In EquityFeedService []

The REST Controller returns: Client Id: Optional[[]]
```

In the REST Controller the code goes inside the if loop and displays nothing on the screen since the List is empty i.e.

```
if(cId.isPresent()) {
           return ResponseEntity.ok(cId);
 }
```

Why?  Why cId.isPresent() returns true and the code goes inside the if loop. Ideally the code should go inside the else loop and throw an Exception since the List is empty. This is happening in case of List only it seems as my other method which has a return type of POJO doesn't have this issue.

Please help me understand this behavior and what should be done to fix this.

Comment: Optional.ofNullable checks for null. Empty lists are not null.

Comment: So how do I solve this. I want to raise a User Defined Exception when the List is empty. How do I solve this scenario.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cId.isPresent()` return `true` because 
         `List<EquityFeeds>` is not null , it's empty list

```
if(!cId.get().isEmpty()) {
   return ResponseEntity.ok(cId);
} else {
   throw new ClientIdNotFoundException(clientId);
}
```

Comment: So how do I solve this? I want to raise an exception and return a JSON response when the List is empty.

Comment: Use list.isEmpty() to Check like cId.get().isEmpty()

Comment: @Abhinash: I tried the code above. If else logic is working fine but in else block it refuses to throw an exception. Does orElseThrow() work only with isPresent() ? I am not able to throw an exception. How do I solve this?

Comment: @sidd my bad, I updated my answer. just use `throw new ClientIdNotFoundException(clientId);`

Answer (score 0):

The reason the `Optional.isPresent` returns `true` is that there is an actual value - an empty `List`. The `Optional` checks whether the value it holds is a `null` or not, nothing else. The `isPresent` checks whether the value is present inside the `Optional`, not inside the `List` itself.

So you have to treat `Optional` a bit different. Moreover, don't use `Optional` like that as substitution to the `if-else` constructs.

Here is a way to go:

```
return cId.filter(Predicate.not(List::Empty))            // if the list is not empty
          .map(ResponseEntity::ok)                       // create a response
          .orElseThrow(() ->                             // or else throw an exception
               new ClientIdNotFoundException(clientId));
```

By the way, you don't want to return `Optional` wrapped inside the `ResponseEntity`. Unwrap it and return the `List` itself. If it is empty or `null` was already handled and the exception would be thrown first.

```
return cId.filter(Predicate.not(List::Empty))            
          .map(Optional::get)                            // exctract from the Optional
          .map(ResponseEntity::ok)
          .orElseThrow(() -> new ClientIdNotFoundException(clientId));
```